# How to Dial Number Programmatically

Tags: blackberry

I want to dial a number when clicked on a button. I couldn't find any docs.

Comment: You get this shorter when you write: Dial number after button press-code please

Comment: I found the solution:

            PhoneArguments phoneArgs = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL,
     Constants.CALL_CENTER_PHONE_NUMBER);
   Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, phoneArgs);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough Code which will help you:

```
PhoneArguments arguments = new PhoneArguments(PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, "dial num.")    
ButtonField buttonField = new ButtonField("Dial",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK)
        {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
            {
                Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, arguments);
                return true;
            }
        };
```

I hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke API allows you to execute the native blackberry applications.

The same way you can open/run/execute the other native blackberry applications like, calendar,camera,phone call, contacts etc..etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following native applications you can execute with custom arguments:

```
      APP_TYPE_ADDRESSBOOK
      APP_TYPE_BLUETOOTH_CONFIG
      APP_TYPE_CALCULATOR
      APP_TYPE_CALENDAR
      APP_TYPE_CAMERA
      APP_TYPE_MAPS
      APP_TYPE_MEMOPAD
      APP_TYPE_MESSAGES
      APP_TYPE_PHONE
      APP_TYPE_SEARCH
      APP_TYPE_TASKS
```